# Open URL using VBA

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to open an URL using VBA. After validating the credentials, the System is Loading and in the mid way page redirected to the login page.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Hi Bala, please add some detail to your question (including the code you've already written) -- also what application are you running this VBA from? See [help] for info on improving the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub OpenURL() 
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("http://www.google.com")
End Sub
```